# What does it mean when I get "Not found" and a black screen when I click on a Logic App?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I'm getting "Not Found" on one third of my Logic Apps. These are older test apps - perhaps three months old. What's causing them not to load?

Answer (score 0):

If you can send me the resource ID of the Logic App it would help (if you can't grab it on the portal - https://resources.azure.com should be able to who you if it's there.  Usually this happens when the Logic App has been deleted by the user (potentially as some other resource group delete), but not sure.

Let me know - happy to help.